# Update Failed: Select Command Denied for User (vahejaba @ localhost)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have an error message in a PHP application that keeps pointing to an Update failing but reports that my Select command is not granted.

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 SELECT
>   command denied to user 'vahejaba'@'localhost' for table 'actionitems'

This is the update method that is triggering a select grant invalid error on vahejaba@loalhost.

Why do I get a select error on update and why is my username incorrect (this is incorrect for some reason I believe that I causing the error)?

Please help.

**database.php**

```
class Database
{
    private static $instance;

    private $dbh;

    private static $dbengine = 'mysql';
    private $dbname;
    private static $dbhost = 'localhost';     

    function __construct()
    {      
        $this->dbname = "vahejaba_projectaim"; //str_replace('.projectaim.tools', '', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']); //Config::$dbname;
        $dbhost = Database::$dbhost;
        $dbengine = Database::$dbengine;
        $username = Config::$username;
        $password = Config::$password;

        try
        {
            $this->dbh = new PDO("$dbengine:host=$dbhost;dbname=$this->dbname", $username, $password);
        }
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            die("Error in establishing connection to database!");
        }
     }

    public function update($table, $colsVals=null, $whereVals=null)
    {
        $table = $this->getTable($table);
        $columns = "";
        $valuelist = array();
        $values = "";
        $params = array();
        $where = $this->where($whereVals);

        $wherestr = $where['wherestring'];
        $whereParams = $where['params'];

        $set = $this->set($colsVals);
        $setVals = $set['set'];
        $setParams = $set['params'];
        $setValsString = $set['setvals'];
        $vals = $set['vals'];
        $params = array_merge($whereParams, $setParams);


        if ($table !== FALSE)
        {
                try
                {
                    $dbname = $this->dbname;
                    $sql = $this->dbh->prepare("UPDATE $table SET $setValsString WHERE $wherestr");

                    $sql->execute($setParams);

                    $this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                }
                catch (PDOException $e)
                {
                    die('Update failed: '.  $e->getMessage());
                }
        }
    }
}
```

**config.php**

```
   class Config
   {    
        static $username = 'vahejaba_user';
   }
```

**manageActionItems.php**

```
class ManageActionItems
{
    private $db;
    private $dbh;
    private $userManager;
    private $cols;
    private $rowCount;
    private $vals;
    private $actionItemGrid;
    private $requiredCols;
    private $projectId;
    private $table;
    private $tool;


    function __construct($excludeCols = array(), $requiredCols = array(), $projectId)
    {
        $this->db = Database::getInstance();
        $this->userManager = new UserManager();
        $this->dbh = $this->db->getHandle();
        $this->table = 'ActionItems';
        $this->tool = 'actionitem';
        $this->requiredCols = $requiredCols;
        $this->projectId = $projectId;
        $this->actionItemGrid = new Grid($this->table, $excludeCols);
        $this->cols = $this->actionItemGrid->getCols();
        $this->rowCount = $this->actionItemGrid->getRowCount();
    }
    public function edit($id)
    {   
        if (isset($_SESSION['errmsg']))
            unset($_SESSION['errmsg']);

        $ymdDueDate = "";
        $ymdAssigned = "";
        $ymdECD = "";
        $ymdClosedDate = "";
        $ymdCompletionDate = "";

        $colsVals = array();

        if (isset($_POST['editAssignedDate']) && $_POST['editAssignedDate'] != "" && $this->checkDate($_POST['editAssignedDate']))
        {
            $mdy = preg_split('/\//',  $_POST['editAssignedDate']);
            $ymdAssigned = "$mdy[2]-$mdy[0]-$mdy[1]";
        }   
        else if (isset($_SESSION['AssignedDate']) && $_SESSION['AssignedDate'] != "")
        {
            $mdy = preg_split('/\//',  $_SESSION['AssignedDate']);
            $ymdAssigned = "$mdy[2]-$mdy[0]-$mdy[1]";
        }
        if (isset($_POST['editDueDate']) && $_POST['editDueDate'] != "" && $this->checkDate($_POST['editDueDate']))
        {
            $mdy = preg_split('/\//',  $_POST['editDueDate']);
            $ymdDueDate = "$mdy[2]-$mdy[0]-$mdy[1]";
        }
        else if (isset($_SESSION['DueDate']) && $_SESSION['DueDate'] != "")
        {
            $mdy = preg_split('/\//',  $_SESSION['DueDate']);
            $ymdDueDate = "$mdy[2]-$mdy[0]-$mdy[1]";
        }

        if (isset($_POST['editECD']) && $_POST['editECD'] != "" && $this->checkDate($_POST['editECD']))
        {
            $mdy = preg_split('/\//',  $_POST['editECD']);
            $ymdECD = "$mdy[2]-$mdy[0]-$mdy[1]";
        }
        else if (isset($_SESSION['ECD']) && $_SESSION['ECD'] != "")
        {
            $mdy = preg_split('/\//',  $_SESSION['ECD']);
            $ymdECD = "$mdy[2]-$mdy[0]-$mdy[1]";
        }

        if (isset($_POST['editClosedDate']) && $_POST['editClosedDate'] != "" && $this->checkDate($_POST['editClosedDate']))
        {
            $mdy = preg_split('/\//',  $_POST['editClosedDate']);
            $ymdClosedDate = "$mdy[2]-$mdy[0]-$mdy[1]";
        }
        else if (isset($_SESSION['ClosedDate']) && $_SESSION['ClosedDate'] != "")
        {
            $mdy = preg_split('/\//',  $_SESSION['ClosedDate']);
            $ymdClosedDate = "$mdy[2]-$mdy[0]-$mdy[1]";
        }

        if (isset($_POST['editCompletionDate']) && $_POST['editCompletionDate'] != "" && $this->checkDate($_POST['editCompletionDate']))
        {
            $mdy = preg_split('/\//',  $_POST['editCompletionDate']);
            $ymdCompletionDate = "$mdy[2]-$mdy[0]-$mdy[1]";
        }
        else if (isset($_SESSION['CompletionDate']) && $_SESSION['CompletionDate'] != "")
        {
            $mdy = preg_split('/\//',  $_SESSION['CompletionDate']);
            $ymdCompletionDate = "$mdy[2]-$mdy[0]-$mdy[1]";
        }

        $this->vals['AssignedDate'] = $ymdAssigned;
        $this->vals['DueDate'] = $ymdDueDate;
        $this->vals['ECD'] = $ymdECD;
        $this->vals['CompletionDate'] = $ymdCompletionDate;
        $this->vals['ClosedDate'] = $ymdClosedDate;



        if (isset($_POST['editAssignedDate']))
            $_SESSION['AssignedDate'] = $_POST['editAssignedDate'];
        if (isset($_POST['editDueDate']))
            $_SESSION['DueDate'] = $_POST['editDueDate'];

        if (isset($_POST['editECD']))            
            $_SESSION['ECD'] = $_POST['editECD'];

        if (isset($_POST['editCompletionDate']))
            $_SESSION['CompletionDate'] = $_POST['editCompletionDate'];
        if (isset($_POST['editClosedDate']))                           
            $_SESSION['ClosedDate'] = $_POST['editClosedDate'];


        $this->saveEditVals();
        if($ymdAssigned != "" && $ymdDueDate != "" && $ymdAssigned > $ymdDueDate)
        {
            $_SESSION['errmsg'] = 'Due Date Must be Greater or Equal to Assigned Date';
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            unset($_SESSION['errmsg']);
        }



        foreach ($this->cols as $col)
        {
            if (array_key_exists($col, $_SESSION))
            {
                if($col != "ApproverID" && $col != "AltOwnerID" && $col != "OwnerID" && $col != "AssignorID" && $col != "AssignedDate" && $col != "DueDate" && $col != "ECD" && $col != "ClosedDate" && $col != "CompletionDate" && $col != "ID" && $col != "ActionItemID" && $col != "ProjectID")
                    $colsVals[$col] = $_SESSION[$col];
                else if($col == 'AssignorID' && isset($_SESSION[$col]) && $_SESSION[$col] != 0)
                    $colsVals[$col] = intval($_SESSION[$col]);
                else if($col == 'AltOwnerID' && isset($_SESSION[$col]) && $_SESSION[$col] != 0)
                    $colsVals[$col] = intval($_SESSION[$col]);
                else if($col == 'OwnerID'  && isset($_SESSION[$col]) && $_SESSION[$col] != 0)
                    $colsVals[$col] = intval($_SESSION[$col]);
                else if($col == 'ApproverID' && isset($_SESSION[$col]) && $_SESSION[$col] != 0)
                    $colsVals[$col] = intval($_SESSION[$col]);
                //else if ($col == 'AssignorID' || $col == 'AltOwnerID' || $col == 'ApproverID' || $col == 'OwnerID' && !isset($_SESSION[$col]))
                //  $colsVals[$col] = 'NULL';
            }

        }

       // $manageLockedFields = new ManageLockedFields('actionitem');

        $colsVals['AssignedDate'] = $ymdAssigned;

        $colsVals['DueDate'] = $ymdDueDate;

        $colsVals['ClosedDate'] = $ymdClosedDate;

        $colsVals['CompletionDate'] = $ymdCompletionDate;

        $colsVals['ECD'] = $ymdECD;

        $where = array();
        if ($id != null)
        {
           $where[] = array('Selector', '=', "'".substr($id, 0, 12)."'");
        }

        $this->db->update($this->table, $colsVals, $where); 
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: If the user doesn't have select access, they can't update either since it will first need to locate (IOW *select*) the row in order to update it. Since it never gets around to the update, the error message will be regarding the user having select access to the table.

Comment: I believe I might be manipulating the underscore somewhere but I don't see it.  It is modifying my username or trimming it.

Comment: Not likely, at least not in the code you posted in your question. More likely is a permission setting in the DB, or the wrong username. Double check the permissions for the user using phpAdmin or similar.

Comment: Sadly, I am using a cpanel on a webhost which only gives me permissions for vahejaba_user, not vahejaba, which is a cpanel login.

Comment: If they don't offer at least phpAdmin, I'd switch hosts. Whatever you might be saving on hosting fees will be eaten up in debugging time rather quickly. I pay about $11 / month for unlimited domains, disk space and bandwidth.

Comment: I am using phpmyadmin and remote sqlyog but only gives me r/w to my databases and information_schema,  I cannot query mysql table to get users/permissions.

Comment: You don't need to query to find that stuff out. Just export the table as SQL and be sure to check the Create Table option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my database (phpmyadmin) I had a trigger that was incorrectly pointing to the wrong username and the wrong database name.  After contacting the web host with no solution I investigated the trigger, uncovering the issue.  Revision of the parameters eliminated the error.